# Store pending NSOperations when an application is killed

Tags: ios, iphone, nsoperation, appdelegate, nsoperationqueue

I am developing a download queue of big files. I manage the `NSOperations` that are downloading or waiting for download in the `NSOperationQueue`, and I also store them in a `NSMutableDictionary` with their Keys.

I'd like to develop the same functionality that the PodCasts app does. I mean, if the user is downloading some podcasts and kill the app completely, if he/she restarts the app, the operations keep downloading where they were.

So, How do they store the pending  operations? I have tried to store the `NSDictionary` of pending `NSOperations` using `userDefaults`, but there is no possibility of do that because of the `NSOperation` does not implements `NSCopying`.

So, I would like to know which is the best way to handle that behaviour...?

Any idea?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I think you can create a entity which stores the progress of your downloading while you keep writing that file on the disc. Update the progress of the entity when you get download a chunk from the networking layer and then in applicationWillTerminate callback store the progress back to the DB. Then when you open the application again, then you can ask for the next chunk from networking layer based on the progress of your download.